# Setting adapter to spinner scrolls recycler view to top

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner and a recycler view in one layout. In my activity's onResume, I'm setting an adapter to the spinner and trying to scroll recycler view to the last visible item that I have saved in the activity's onPause. The problem is that setting adapter to spinner, scrolls recycler view to top! I've tested if I don't set the adapter there would be no problem. Here's my code:

```
override fun onPause() {
      super.onPause()
      currentVisiblePosition = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
}

override fun onResume() {
      super.onResume()
      val list = ArrayList<String>()
      list.add("item1")
      list.add("item2")
      spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
      (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPosition(currentVisiblePosition)
}
```

Do you guys know where the problem is?

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I want the recycler view to scroll to the last visible row but it doesn't.

Comment: anything in logcat? and try that in onpostresume, might work

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh None of them worked unfortunately. This is the weirdesr problem I've ever faced.